# Spring security: Apply filter to only an endpoint

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

Currently, I've two kind of endpoints into my service:

- `/portal/**`: I need to add a filter `PortalAuthorizationFilter`
- The other ones: I need to add a filter `OthersAuthorizationFilter`

It's important that `OthersFilter` has not to be applied on `/portal/**` calls.

I've created a `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`. My current code is:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled=true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
            .addFilterBefore(new JWTExceptionHandlerFilter(objectMapper, messageSource), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .cors().and()
            .csrf().disable()
            .antMatcher("/portal/**")
            .addFilter(new PortalAuthorizationFilter())
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .addFilter(new OthersAuthorizationFilter());
    }
}
```

I've debugged this code when a call is made to `/portal/**`, `PortalAuthorizationFilter` is reached, but then `OthersAuthorizationFilter` is reached as well.

I don't quite figure out how to solve it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Before I search a dupe target and you delete also this questions, I comment first: You added both filter to the configuration, so both are applied.

Comment: If you don't want to apply `OthersAuthorizationFilter` remove `.addFilter(new OthersAuthorizationFilter())` from your configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create another configuration class which will also extend WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter, there you match your url with antMatchers and add your filter. Whichever pattern match will run that security configuration
Read this [post](http://blog.florian-hopf.de/2017/08/spring-security.html)

Comment: That wasn't the question of OP. However, your are right, configure `OthersAuthorizationFilter` makes no sense, if it shouldn't be applied.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled=true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.antMatcher("/portal/**").... //the configuration only 
              //applies when sb hitting /portal/**
    }
}
```

if you want another configuration for another url you need overwrite another `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled=true)
@Order(101) //@Order(100) is default
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http... //without antMatcher(...) default will be used "/**", 
                //so it take all request. So the order of this class should be 
                // higher
    }
}
```

If you want use filter approach (`.addFilter(new OthersAuthorizationFilter());` )then in your `doFilter` method you should implement:

```
doFilter(...) {
  if(match(request, "/portal/**")
    ....
}
```

Unfortunately `AuthenticationProvider` will not give you such possibility, it doesn't know about url, just credentials. If you want more [read spring-security-architecture](https://spring.io/guides/topicals/spring-security-architecture/).

But I thing you want [to delegate authorization](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/#_clients_and_authentication)

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use a delegate pattern. Imagine if you have a filter that looks like this

```java
public class PickAndChooseFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private AntPathRequestMatcher matcher = new AntPathRequestMatcher("/portal/**");
    private final Filter portalAuthorizationFilter;
    private final Filter othersAuthorizationFilter;

    public PickAndChooseFilter(Filter portalAuthorizationFilter, Filter othersAuthorizationFilter) {
        this.portalAuthorizationFilter = portalAuthorizationFilter;
        this.othersAuthorizationFilter = othersAuthorizationFilter;
    }


    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
        if (matcher.matches(request)) {
            portalAuthorizationFilter.doFilter(request, response, filterChain);
        } else {
            othersAuthorizationFilter.doFilter(request, response, filterChain);
        }
    }
}
```

then instead of

```
.addFilter(new PortalAuthorizationFilter())
.addFilter(new OthersAuthorizationFilter())
```

you'd simply have

```
.addFilter(new PickAndChooseFilter(
    new PortalAuthorizationFilter(),
    new OthersAuthorizationFilter()
)
```